# Enhancing search using Fuzzy Logic in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, search, mongodb

**Brief Description:**

In my **NodeJS** Application, I have a model called **User**.

**User.js**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }
};
```

My application consists users searching functionality using **name** attribute. For that I used find users using exact name as below(I am using **MongoDB** as my Database). My User Controller as below.

**UserController.js**

```
 var name = req.param('name');

 User.find({ name: { 'contains': name } }).exec(function (err, results) {
     if (err) {
         return res.serverError(err);
     }
     return res.send(results);
 });
```

Now I need to enhance my searching functionality.

As an example if my DB contains record as **Michael** and if I searched as **micel**, Michael should be given as a search result.

For that I used Fuzzy Logic Algorithm and I used **[fuzzy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy)** `npm` package. Now my implementation is as below.

**UserController.js**

```
var fuzzy = require('fuzzy');

module.exports = {

    search: function (req, res) {

        var term = req.param('name');
        var thisCtrl = this;

        User.find().exec(function (err, users) {

            if (err) {
                return res.serverError(err);
            } 
            thisCtrl.createSearchQuery(term, users, function (orQuery) {
                User.find({or: orQuery}).exec( function (err, finalResulst) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.serverError(err);
                    } 
                    return res.send(finalResulst)
                })
            })
        });
    },

    createSearchQuery: function (term, users, cb) {

        var userNamesArr = [];
        var or = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            userNamesArr.push(users[i].name)
        }

        var results = fuzzy.filter(term, userNamesArr);
        var matches = results.map(function(el) { return el.string; });

        for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {

            var tempTerm = { name: { 'contains' : matches[i] }};
            or.push(tempTerm)
        }
        cb(or);
    }
};
```

**This is working as I needed.**

**But My Question is,**

I am getting all the users in my DB and create search term using Fuzzy Logic and finding again in **User** collection. Now this is ok if I have only about 100 user records. But the time when User collection contains **Millions** of user records , Will this causes to performance issue to my application or is there a **Better Approach** than this I should follow.

**Sorry for my bad English and Suggestions are highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question

> *"Will this causes to performance issue to my application or is there a Better Approach than this I should follow."*

Well that will depend on a lot of factors.

- 1million clients.
- [fuzzy.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy) and its performance.
- A single medium level server.

### State of development

First a quick look at the link you provided to [fuzzy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzy) and at the bottom of the page you find the ToDo list which contains 2 points of interest

> 3. Async batch updates so the UI doesn't block for huge sets. Or maybe Web Workers?
> 4. Performance performance performance!

Following through to the [gitHub repository](https://github.com/mattyork/fuzzy) and we find that the last activity was 3 years ago. This suggests (not implies) that development has ended. That a key issue recognized by the developers (performance) will not be worked on in the near future.

### Performance

To try and determine the performance per search entry I went to their demo and timed the search over several differently size lists of names, and search strings.

The performance test shows a slightly below linear complexity (in the range of 628 - 1,250,000 names), however its too close to call and the safe bet is its linear. It searched 1.25million names in ~1 +/- 0.2seconds

#### Tests method

The test was performed in the console running the following snippet many times

```
t = performance.now();
res = fuzzy.filter(searchStr, data);
totalTime += performance.now() - t;
count ++;
```

A complex [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), on the same data required 1/10th the time.

```
t = performance.now();
res = data.filter(name => regExpSearch.test(name));
totalTime += performance.now() - t;
count ++;
```

### Conclusion

What Node.js does well is IO, and what is does not do well is processing.

Assuming one medium level server.

- 1 second for a search is a very long time.
- Fuzzy.js performance is unlikely to change.
- A response time over a second puts your site in the bottom 20% of services, and is unacceptable.
- I estimate that at 30 thousand users performance will become a serious problem (see below)

If you are serving 1million active users, (using the 20/80 rule) with 20% of users visiting your site one day a year 20% of them once a month and 20% of them once a week (~600,000 searches a year) with users geographically clustered resulting in significant peak times.

It is highly likely that you will regularly have 30+ concurrent queries and a few times a year you can expect 300, in which case your server will be blocked for over 5 minutes.

<sup>(**NOTE**) these are very rough estimates based on one search per user per visit.</sup>

### The answers

> *"Will this causes to performance issue to my application or..."*

Yes for a very heavy trafficked site this will present a serious performance issue.

No for a very small traffic loads nobody will notice.

> *"...is there a Better Approach than this I should follow."*

Yes of course there is, use a [`regExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), and there are many more. But I can not hand out advice on speculation. The information given above is already dubious as it is based on a single request rather than the site/service as a whole.

### Refection

Well gee... any nerd knows this...

1+ million regular users is cash in the bank.

A service must start somewhere and that is with a few users, with growth being gradual and predictable (once moving). If you are monetizing the service then growth is great and not a problem (if managed well).

Start with the basics and work your way up. Replacing infrastructure (the search methods, upgrading the server/s) is part of the business. Performance is the least of your initial problems.

If you plan for viral growth then you are in the realm of highly speculative investment capital. Outsource a solution to people that have the experience or you **will** miss a lucrative opportunity.

If you plan to provide a free service for 1+ million users, good on you :), but you will need to have a fairly deep pocket.